# Centering caption in subfloat with a forced linebreak

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I have a few `subfloat` captions that are too short to have an automatic linebreak, but I want to force one and still have centering among the lines:

Basically I would like `a` and `b` to be like `c` ...

[image: subfigures]

How can I do it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
\centering
\hspace*{-0cm}
    \subfloat[$v=0$\newline$\omega = \omega_2$]{\includegraphics[scale =0.58]{"satspecK1".pdf} }%
    \quad 
    \subfloat[general $v$\newline general $\omega$]{\includegraphics[scale =0.58]{"satspecK2".pdf} }%
    \quad 
    \subfloat[$v = \pm (\omega_1 - \omega_2)/2k$\newline$\omega = (\omega_1 + \omega_2)/2$]{\includegraphics[scale =0.58]{"satspecK3".pdf} }%
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:Ksatspec}%
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: Never use `\newline` inside a `\parbox` or a caption typeset by the `caption`, `subcaption` or `subfig` package, you will get weird results, so use `\\ ` instead. (The reason for this: `\\ ` is re-defined for parboxes (in `\@parboxrestore`) so it will behave reasonable, but `\newline` is not, for whatever reason.)

Comment: if i understood your question correctly, you like to have centered only caption content and hanging caption label?

Comment: If you want to align equations inside a caption, you should delete this question and start another one.